# rearrange multidimensional array in cakephp 2.2

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional assoc $modules array in cakephp 2.2.3:

```
array(
    'type1' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'name' => 'name16',
            'type' => '1',
            'category' => 'categoryC',
            'zone' => 'zone1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'name' => 'name17',
            'type' => '1',
            'category' => 'categoryB',
            'zone' => 'zone1'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'name' => 'name18',
            'type' => '1',
            'category' => 'categoryA',
            'zone' => 'zone3'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'name' => 'name19',
            'type' => '1',
            'category' => 'categoryC',
            'zone' => 'zone3'
        ),
        (int) 4 => array(
            'name' => 'name22',
            'type' => '1',
            'category' => 'categoryA',
            'zone' => 'zone2'
        )
    ),
    'type2' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'name' => 'name1',
            'type' => '2',
            'category' => 'categoryB',
            'zone' => 'zone2'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'name' => 'name2',
            'type' => '2',
            'category' => 'categoryB',
            'zone' => 'zone2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'name' => 'name3',
            'type' => '2',
            'category' => 'categoryA',
            'zone' => 'zone1'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'name' => 'name4',
            'type' => '2',
            'category' => 'categoryC',
            'zone' => 'zone3'
        ),
        (int) 4 => array(
            'name' => 'name5',
            'type' => '2',
            'category' => 'categoryA',
            'zone' => 'zone3'
        )
    )
)
```

and I want to rearrange it like

```
array(
    'zone1' => array(
        'type1' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'name17',
                'type' => '1',
                'category' => 'categoryB'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'name' => 'name16',
                'type' => '1',
                'category' => 'categoryC'
            )
        ),
        'type2' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'name3',
                'type' => '2',
                'category' => 'categoryA'
            )
        )
    ),
    'zone2' => array(
        'type1' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'name22',
                'type' => '1',
                'category' => 'categoryA'
            )
        ),
        'type2' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'name1',
                'type' => '2',
                'category' => 'categoryB'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'name' => 'name2',
                'type' => '2',
                'category' => 'categoryB'
            )
        )
    ),
    'zone3' => array(
        'type1' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'name18',
                'type' => '1',
                'category' => 'categoryA'
            ),
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'name19',
                'type' => '1',
                'category' => 'categoryC'
            )
        ),
        'type2' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'name' => 'name5',
                'type' => '2',
                'category' => 'categoryA'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'name' => 'name4',
                'type' => '2',
                'category' => 'categoryC'
            )
        )
    )   
)
```

where 'category' should be sorted alphabetically within each parent 'type'

I tried with

```
$modules = Hash::combine($modules, '{n}', '{n}.{n}', '{s}.{s}.{n}.zone');
```

but with no success. I guess I'm not using Hash::combine as I should...
Thanks, Marius

Comment: I think the answer to this question will greatly vary depending on your answer to the following question. Are the zone numbers in your original array "dynamic" or are there a fixed number of zones, zone1, zone2, zone3. If they are fixed you may be able to use array_search() for each zone.

Comment: Hi Tim, the zone names in my array are dynamic, there are no presets, there is not a fixed number of them. Thanks!

Comment: I'm scratching my head on this one. I know your page load times will get unbearable as you grow in zone numbers and have to nest a bunch of foreach loops. Curious to see if anyone comes up with some good solutions. You are probably on the right track with the Hash class but I am not that well versed on it.

Comment: Could you use Set::extract to get all the different zone numbers to start? and then Set::sort to finalize the array? http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Utility-Libraries/Set.html

Comment: Hi Tim, I understand the use of Set::extract to get the zones, but don't understand how can I use Set::sort to add the types to the zones...

Comment: The sort was to hopefully point you in a direction to sort your categories alphabetically.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but the sort is the last problem, I need to get that array structure first. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a foreach inside a foreach to walk through your array and construct a new one based on your preference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was hoping I could use some optimized cakephp function for this, but eventually I think I would end up making nested foreach loops to get it done.

Comment: in the time it took you to ask the question you would've been able to write 2 highly optimized loops.